# How to run an existing moodle environment on a Testbed server

Tags: php, moodle, apache2.2, centos6.5

I've recently started working as a Junior Network Engineer and as my first task I was assigned to make a simple modification on php.ini file in moodle. Therefore, first I setup moodle environment on my laptop with Apache2 and Ubuntu 20.4. Then I tested my modification locally. That was ok.

However, before make the same changes to the live server, I wanted to test that on the Testbed server as well. A replica of the live moodle server has been uploaded into the testbed server. However, initially the problem was that whenever I tried to run moodle on the testbed server, that redirected into the live server, and therefore I could not test my modifications.

Later I made few changes in the 'config.php' and 'login.php' in moodle directory, which have been presented in the images. With those changes, now the login page can be run locally on the testbed server. But still, when I try to login to the system, the page redirects to the live webpage.

Therefore, I appreciate it very much if someone could help me resolve this issue.

Thank you!

Testbed server information:

OS- CentOS 6.5

PHP version-7.2.30

server-Apache2

Moodle version-3.6.4

[config.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJAF3.png)

[login.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6keL.png)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html dir="ltr" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TestBed Server ULMS | ***</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/all.css">
    <link href="assets/css_002.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="core/first"
            src="assets/first.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="core/event"
            src="assets/event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery"
            src="assets/jquery-3.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="page-login-index"
      class="format-site  path-login gecko dir-ltr lang-en yui-skin-sam yui3-skin-sam moodle-wit-ie pagelayout-login course-1 context-1 notloggedin  jsenabled"
      style="background-image: url(''); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;">
<div id="page-wrapper" class="login-page-wrapper">
    <div>
        <a class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#maincontent">Skip to main content</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/yui_combo_004.php"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript-static.js"></script>
    <style>
        .btn-info {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #5bc0de !important;
            border-color: #5bc0de !important;
        }
    </style>


    <div id="page" class="container-fluid mt-0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
        <div id="page-content" class="row">
            <div id="region-main-box" class="col-12">
                <section id="region-main" class="col-12">
                    <div id="login__banner">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img id="login__banner-logo" src="assets/lms_logo_aquanas.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <span class="notifications" id="user-notifications"></span>
            <div role="main"><span id="maincontent"></span>
                        <div class="my-1 my-sm-5"></div>
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="login__container" style="margin-top: 130px;">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-block login-card-block">
                                        <div class="card-title text-xs-center">
                                           <!-- <div id="login__moodle-logo" style="height: 70px;">
                                                <h2 class="text-center"></h2>
                                            </div>-->
                                            <!--<div id="login__avatar-container" style="display: none;">
                                                <img src="assets/no_profile_img.jpg">
                                            </div>-->
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <form class="mt-3" action="https://192.168.50.20/moodle/login/index.php" method="post" id="login" name="login">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="username" class="sr-only">
                                                            Username
                                                        </label>
                                                        <input name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Number / Staff Username"                                                         type="text">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                                        <input name="password" id="password" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3" id="loginbtn">Log in
                                                    </button>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <div class="forgetpass mt-3">
                                                    <p><a href="https://192.168.50.20/login/forgot_password.php">Forgotten
                                                        your username or password?</a></p>
                                                </div>


                                               <!--<div id="login__support-container">
                                                   <a class="login__support login__student-support" href="http://***" target="_blank" style="text-align:                                                                  center;"><img src="asset$
                           <a class="login__support login__student-support" href="http://***" target="_blank" style="text-align:                                                                   center;"><img src="asset$
                                               </div>-->
                                               <!--<div id="login__support-container">
                                                   <a class="login__support login__student-support"
                                                      href="#"
                                                      target="_blank"><img
                                                           src="assets/support-icon.png"><span
                                                           class="login__support-text">Student Support</span></a>
                                                   <a class="login__support login__staff-support"
                                                      href="#"
                                                      target="_blank"><img
                                                           src="assets/academic-icon.png"><span
                                                           class="login__support-text">Staff Support</span></a>
                                               </div>-->

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px">Powered by <a href="http://www.moodle.org" target="_blank"><img id="moodle" src="assets/moodlelogo.png" style="height: 20px; vertical-align:$
    <p  style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px"></p>
</div>
<div id="yui3-css-stamp" style="position: absolute !important; visibility: hidden !important" class=""></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see the login.php file?

Comment: @mcroteau Sure, the login.php file is as shown above